# VSTS build .NET ASP to Web Service using Continuous Deployment

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I have a solution that has 10 projects. 1 web site and 1 web service.

I setup a continuous deployment in Azure for the web app. The continuous deployment is confused due to the multiple projects. How do i scope my deployment to deploy the web site correctly.

The error is

```
Errors (1)
Error: More than one package matched with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip. Please restrain the search pattern.
Work items
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a single package explicitly by name instead of `**\*.zip.`

Comment: I found it in the release section. Thanks